# Why the compiler is showing true?

Tags: c++

The output should be false, as false&&true is false. However, the compiler is giving 1 as output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 13;

    bool flag = true;
    cout << ((b - 4) < a) && !flag;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Operator precedence between << and && https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `<<` has higher precedence than `&&`, your expression should be:

```
cout << (((b-4)<a) && !flag);
```

A more detailed explanation:

One of the first things that any C++ compiler does when processing your source code is to construct an *abstract syntax tree* (AST) representing your source code. The AST is a tree structure that encodes -among other things- the precedence of different unary and binary operators. An AST for the expression you have written (`cout << ((b - 4) < a) && !flag;`) would look something like this:

```
     &&
    /  \
   <<   !
  /  \   \
cout  <   flag
     / \   
    -   a
   / \
  b   4
```

How do we know that e.g. `&&` must be the root of the AST or that sub-expressions in parentheses are evaluated first? Because the C++ [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules say so. These are similar to the rules we use when doing math on paper (e.g. do multiplication before addition) but extended to all operators supported by the language.

We can use the AST to see in what order the sub-expressions of this expression are evaluated, the general rule being that evaluation happens in "bottom up" order, i.e. from the leaves to the root of the AST. In this particular case, evaluation could (conceptually) happen like this:

```
// left subtree
b - 4 = 9
9 < a = true
cout << true = cout (operator<< returns a reference to cout)

// right subtree
!flag = false
```

And finally we're left with `cout && false`. `cout` implements `operator bool` which allows it to be implicitly cast to `bool`, yielding `true` if the stream has no errors. Because that is the case here, we finally have `true && false == false` the value of which is unused.

So you can see that your program outputs `1` because during evaluation of the left subtree, `cout << true` is executed. Afterwards, `cout && !flag`, though well formed, essentially does nothing because it has no side effects and you don't use the result.

Comment: Can you please tell me step by step that how the compiler will give output.

Comment: @MazharAbbasZaidi: Sure, give me a minute.

Comment: @PeterSmith sure, I'll be waiting

Comment: Great answer @Peter!